# How to implement certificate authentication for a .netcore2.1 webapi

Tags: c#, certificate, webapi

I’m developing a webapi(using mvc pattern) based on .netcore2.1, I was required to secure the webapi using certificate authentication(Both mutual authentication and client certificate authentication are fine, though mutual is more secure), the webapi is going to be deployed to Azure app service when it’s ready. I know .netcore3.1 has a good nuget package: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Certificate which can easily implement cert authentication however my build environment only support .netcore2.1.

This is a pretty big question, if you happen to know the the 'best practice' , please share, i'm new to this area, it would be great if you have sample code.

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53761660/net-core-web-api-with-client-certificate-authentication)

Comment: Thank you John, actually i looked that post, the accepted answer is using idunno package or the package in .netcore 3.0 or above which doesn't supported in my production environment.

Comment: There is a branch for older .net core versions https://github.com/blowdart/idunno.Authentication

Comment: Thank you Daniel, however we can't use a non-MS shipped package in our environment